# Can’t boot into Ubuntu after installing

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu like I have many times before on my new Acer Aspire laptop and restarted the machine once it had done installing. The installation was completely successful but once I restart and take my USB stick out so it boots off my HDD, it gets to the boot screen and some white text pops up in the top left for a split second and all I can make out from it is it saying something about 'Failed to...' on the top line and 'Reset System' at the very bottom and after the text flashes the systems just reboots and goes in a loop... help?

The text specifically says...

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\amd64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\amd64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start HoldManager: Not Found
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
Creating boot entry "Boot0010" with label "ubuntu" for file "\EFI\ubuntu\shim64.efi"

Reset System
```

*Might have got a couple of things wrong because the 'removing quiet splash' method did not work so I had to take a rather blurry picture of it on my phone quickly when it popped up...*

Comment: At the GRUB boot menu, hit the "e" key, locate "quiet splash", remove those two words, then hit control-x or F10 to continue booting. You should now be able to see what the error messages are. Add that info into your question. Report back.

Comment: There we go, I have edited it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this one, but there's now enough info for somebody else to help you. Sorry.

Comment: So you haven’t managed to boot it even once? I’d try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You should add the URL with details to your question if it does not solve the problem automatically.